# how to write/log exact powershell command executed?

Tags: angular, powershell

I've written a powershell script to do a deployment.  Part of this script executes the angular cli like this:

```
ng build --env=qa --target=development
```

The command above works as-is from cmd on my local machine but it's returning an error on the build server. I'm currently writing out variables but I'm trying to narrow down potential discrepancies b/t my local environment and the build server to keep the test as consistent and reproducible as possible.

The ng build command above is created on the build server based on calculated variables. I want to capture the exact command that gets executed from the ps1 on the build server.  Is there a way to do this from a ps1?

Comment: You can use [showargs.exe](http://beta.itprotoday.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell) to output a literal command line in PowerShell.

Comment: Take a look at transcripts in PowerShell. Documented here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687007.aspx